# How to compare part of two file names and use 'cat' to append them together

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, cat

Here is my code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for file1 in 
 /net/zmf8/cb/37/lxy161830/work/target_readcount/*.readcount.txt;
 do
     for file2 in /net/zmf8/cb/37/lxy161830/work/nontarget_readcount/*.nontargetreawdcount.txt;
         if [ $( basename${file1:0:1} ) == $( basename${file2:0:1} ) ];then
             cat $file1 $file2 > '*.readcount.txt'
         fi
 done
```

But i just don't know how to compare two file names only the '*' part. And it always replied

```
./integrate.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
./integrate.sh: line 5: `  if [ $( basename${file1:0:1} ) == $(basename${file2:0:1} ) ];then'
```

Answer (score 1):

You inner loop needs a `do` and a `done` of its own. I proposed an edit for that.

If you just want to skip comparing the same file to itself, you could try this:

```
case $file1 in
     $file2) continue;;
esac
```

Though as I read it, the filenames (even just the basenames) will never collide.
`*.nontargetreadcount.txt` will never match `*.readcount.txt` because of the dot.

Also, I don't think you want `*` in your output filename. Maybe something like

```
cat $file1 $file2 > /tmp/$( basename $file1 ).$( basename $file2 )
```